# Is there a way to run tags as individual tests?

Tags: java, karate, junit5

I have a package in my **src/test/java** directory called **com/example/alan/test**.  Inside that package I have my KarateTest.java file and a **features** directory, which is full of .feature files.  Each feature file has exactly one tag at the very top e.g. @Feature1, @Feature2, and so on.

Is there a way to use [JUnit5's dynamic tests](https://www.baeldung.com/junit5-dynamic-tests) to run each tag/.feature file as individual tests?

I ask as I want to have a config.yaml file that lists what tags I want to run in a given test run e.g.

```
tags:
  - '@Feature1'
  - '@Feature3'
```

I read this file in and am attempting to run a test per tag e.g.

```
  public class KarateTest {

    @TestFactory
    Stream<DynamicTest> runKarateTestsDynamically() {
        List<String> tags = ConfigUtils.getTags(); //read the tags in from the yaml config file
        return tags.stream().map(this::createDynamicTest);
    }

    private DynamicTest createDynamicTest(String tag) {
        return dynamicTest("Run Karate Test with Tag: " + tag, () -> {
            System.out.println("Running Karate Test with Tag: " + tag);
            Karate.run("classpath:com/example/alan/test/features").tags(tag).outputHtmlReport(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Not sure if this would be a way to do it, but I don't get any test output at all and the features aren't running.  Thanks

Comment: try @ParameterizedTest

Comment: this is certainly not supported. no other team has requested this - so your best bet is to contribute code via a PR